# Meaning of "quod" in this context

Tags: classical-latin, meaning

M. Valerius Martialis: Epigrammata III.44 recites

> Occurrit tibi nemo quod libenter, 
> quod, quacumque venis, fuga est et ingens 
> circa te, Ligurine, solitudo,
> quid sit, scire cupis?

What is the meaning of "quod" in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means "that." The basic structure of the sentence is:

> Scire cupis quid sit **quod** nemo tibi libenter occurrit?
> *You want to know why it is **that** nobody meets with you gladly?*

In the phrase *est, quod* the *quod* does not translate to a specific English word; it depends on how you render the whole thing in English, e.g. *hoc est, quod ad vos venio*, "that is **why** I come to you" etc.

Comment: What is the role of pres. subj., "sit" in "quid sit"? I thought it was--you want to know what may be ("scire cupis quid sit") that ("quod") nobody meets with you willingly?

Comment: @tony Ugh, I overlooked that. My analysis is wrong a it stands.

Comment: I've updated the answer.